# Maximum trigger depth exceeded error while update

Tags: apex, trigger, after-trigger

am getting the following error:

> CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, Effectivefilingdate: maximum
>   trigger depth exceeded Patent trigger event AfterUpdate

below is my code-what is the change i want to do...

```
trigger Effectivefilingdate on Patent__c (after insert,after update) {
if(trigger.isAfter)
if(trigger.isinsert || trigger.isupdate)
{
    List<Patent__c> objPatsToUpdate = NEW List<Patent__c>();
    Set<Id> PatIds = new Set<Id>();
    for (Patent__c Pat : Trigger.new){
    PatIds.add(Pat.id);
    }
    for (Patent__c objPatent : [select Id,Effective_Filing_Date__c,Application_Date__c,Priority_Dates__c from Patent__c where Id IN:PatIds]) 
    {
        //Patent__c oldpat = Trigger.oldMap.get(objPatent.Id);

        if (objPatent.Priority_Dates__c == Null)
        {
            objPatent.Effective_Filing_Date__c = objPatent.Application_Date__c;
        }
        if (objPatent.Priority_Dates__c !=null)
        {
            List<date> lstDtPrioirtyDates = New List<date>();
            List<date> lstDtPrioirtyDates1 = New List<date>();
            List<String> lstStrPriorityDates = objPatent.Priority_Dates__c.replaceAll( '\\s+', '').split(',');
            date mydate;
            system.debug(lstStrPriorityDates);
            for(string st : lstStrPriorityDates)
            {
                date dt = date.valueof(st);
                if(mydate == null)
                {
                    mydate = dt;
                }
                else{
                if(mydate > dt)
                    mydate=dt;
                }
            }
            objPatent.Effective_Filing_Date__c = mydate;
            system.debug('Small date'+mydate);
        }
        objPatsToUpdate.add(objPatent);
    }
    if(!objPatsToUpdate.isEmpty())
    {
    update objPatsToUpdate;
    } 
 }}
```

Comment: See the many existing answers https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/search?q=maximum+trigger+depth+exceeded.

Answer (score 2):

Your trigger is recursing because, in an `after update` trigger, you perform a DML `update` on the same objects received by the trigger without altering the fields that cause your trigger to process those objects.

You make changes to `Patent__c` objects under two conditions, both based on `Priority_Dates__c`. However, your code doesn't change `Priority_Dates__c` when it performs an update. This ensures that your `after update` trigger, when it runs during the new `update` DML you fire, will process those same records again, and update them again, until you hit the stack depth limit.

It appears to me that your trigger could be run `before insert` and `before update` rather than after, when you can directly make changes to the objects in `Trigger.New` rather than querying and firing another DML update. This would prevent recursion without having to implement a more complex recursion-prevention architecture.